# C++ Convert String To Integer Array

Tags: c++, arrays

hello this is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void bubbleSort(int ar[]);

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    char t = 'f';
    char *t1;
    char **t2;
    cout<<t;


    int choice;

    std::cout << "\nWelcome to the algortihm tester!\n";
    std::cout << "What algorithm would you like to test?";
    std::cout << "\nChoose: \n1.Bubble Sort\n2.Selection Sort\n3.Insertion Sort\n";
    scanf("\n%d", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:


        std:: string trash;
        std::string str;
        std::cout << "\nINPUT:";
        std::getline (std::cin,str);
        std::getline(std::cin,trash);
        int* myarray = new int[str.size() ];
        std::copy( str.begin(), str.end(), myarray);
        bubbleSort(myarray);
        break;
    }
}


void bubbleSort(int myarray[])
{

    int length = sizeof(myarray)/sizeof(myarray[0]);
    int i;
    for(i=(length-1); i >= 0; i--)
    {

        for(int j =1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            if (myarray[j-1]>myarray[j])
            {
                int temp = myarray[j-1];
                myarray[j-1]=myarray[j];
                myarray[j]=temp;


            }

        }

    }

}
```

I'm trying to make a program that accepts input from a user, a string, then it gets copied to an array, and that array gets passed to the function `bubbleSort`. But when I run it i get the result as 0, which means, the string didn't get copied to the array correctly. I'm new to c++, and isn't really that familiar with the syntaxes, how do I turn the string to an integer array correctly?

Comment: Your code, as-is, is broken. The `main` function and `switch` statement are incomplete.

Comment: I only took those, code because I only wanted to evaluate the bubblesort which is in case 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get input of x ints to throw into the `bubblesort` and sort them.

You can use a `vector`, to input as many integers you want, and then you can copy that `vector` to an `int` `array` to use with the `bubblesort`.

It's most definitely not the best way to sort something but, it seems that you are doing it for practice, so this would be one way of achieving what you want.

I could give you a code example if you like. Let me know.
Also, your code is broken as is.

Why did you think of using a String in the first place?

**Code**

```
 vector<int> array;
 cout << "Enter numbers\n";
 int tmp;
 while (cin >> tmp)
     array.push_back(temp);


while (cin >> tmp)
```

This line here, loops the line below it, until you give a value that's not an int. After that you do something like.

```
int *arr = new int[array.size()];
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), arr);
```

And you're done.
Hopefully I helped you.
**Please** if anyone sees anything wrong with my solution, comment to fix it

Comment: ohhhhhhh, so there is this "vector" , can you give me an example of how to do this? I thought that turning the string to an integer array, would do the job, so I can sort them out in the bubble sort, and yes im doing this for practice. I wrote this in python and java, but can't figure it out on c++.